# Why it has $-\int_\Sigma\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} ds=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega}|D u|^2dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

In the book "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order", and in section 2.9, about the definition of capacity of $\Omega$,why it has $-\int_\Sigma\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} ds=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega}|D u|^2dx$.

Shouldn't it be $-\int_\Sigma\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu} ds=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega}\Delta udx$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked it up. $u$ satisfies some additional properties:
$$u=1 \mbox{ on }\Sigma=\partial\Omega,\ u=0\mbox{ suitably at }\infty,\ \Delta u=0\mbox{ on }\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega$$
Then partial integration yields (the boundary term at $\infty$ vanishes, because $u=0$ there)
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega}|\nabla u|^2\, dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nabla u\, dx = -\int_{\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega} \Delta u u\, dx + \int_{\partial\Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial(-\nu)} u\,ds.$$
$\nu$ is the outer unit normal of $\Omega$, but we apply the divergence theorem on $\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega$, hence we need the outer unit normal of $\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega$, i.e. $-\nu$.
The conditions on $u$ now yield
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n-\Omega}|\nabla u|^2\, dx = -\int_{\partial\Omega} \frac{\partial u}{\partial\nu}\,ds.$$